# PHP DateTime::createFromFormat not working

Tags: php, date

`DateTime::createFromFormat` doesn't appear to be working correctly, does anyone know a reason and/or how to fix it?

Given this code:

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('m', '02')->format('m'));
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('n', '2')->format('n'));
```

My expected output would be

```
02
2
```

However I actually get:

```
03
3
```

Example:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/e4hns6

I've tested this on a multitude of servers including:

- Win PHP 5.4
- Linux PHP 5.3
- Viper Codepad

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#77490

Comment: @tpaksu thanks, that explains why it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

> "If format does not contain the character ! then portions of the
>   generated time which are not specified in format will be set to the
>   current system time."

The following should work as expected:

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', '02')->format('m'));
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('!n', '2')->format('n'));

# result:
string(2) "02"
string(1) "2"
```

Comment: Well that works for my use case. But out of curiosity, what if I wanted to only parse the month, and use the current year/day/time?

Comment: @Petah, that's what you are doing (with your original code). But there aren't 30 days in February, the second month, so it's advancing to the third month. The `!` defaults to 1970-01-01 00:00:00, so it avoids that problem.